# How do i setup Api Gateway to access multiple private NLBs, each NLB being in a separate VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I have 4 applications running behind NLBs [so 4 VPCs and 4 NLB dns] that I need to access via an API gateway.
I have separate API gateway resource per NLB, for this, I create a VPCLink.
I cannot pass multiple NLB target arns to a single VPC Link so I create 4 separate VPC links

The problem is with the deployment I am unable to pass the 4 vpclink ids as a stage variable since the stage variable `vpcLinkId` takes only 1 vpclink id.

is there a stage variable for multiple vpclink ids or should I create separate deployment stage per vpclink id?

Comment: What is the relationship between API Gateway and the NLBs? Are they the same environment different verbs?

Comment: yeah they are in the same account, network load balancer is attached to an API gateway path via vpc link

Answer (score 0):

I skipped the stage variable in the deployment stage & it worked so I suppose `vpcLinkId` isn't required